# Trying to understand the logic of touch handling in Android

Tags: java, android

I've got a basic understanding of Java but I admit interfaces still confuse me a little bit. I'm working through an Android programming book and the whole section about gestures is baffling me. I'm using the following code to handle touch events that correspond to gestures, it works as I copied it straight from the book but I'm trying to understand why it works.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import androidx.core.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    private GestureDetectorCompat gDetector;
    private TextView gestureText;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gestureText = findViewById(R.id.gestureStatusText);
        
        this.gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        gDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    // ... other event handlers
}
```

A few lines are confusing me.
Why does this line pass in the 'this' identifier for its two parameters? I think I get that 'this' refers to the current class so can other classes be passed in?

```
this.gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
```

What is this method doing? Specifically why is the created class used on the first line and why is the super method returned? Why both?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Thank you for any response, Android is really confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see `new GestureDetectorCompat();` is a public constructor and it takes in 2 parameters `Context` `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`
Even in this case, the `this` keyword is used in the same context and meaning.

One thing you are missing is, that the `this` keyword represents the current "Object" and not the current "Class". So, if and when you create an object of this "Interface" (by implementing it in another class of course), the `this` keyword will represent that specific object.

---

The `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` callback will notify users when a particular motion event has occurred. This class should only be used with MotionEvents reported via touch

`this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);`  this will indicate that the event you want to handle is successful or not by showing true or false.

`super.onTouchEvent(event);` this is a call to use all other gestures events 
[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) You can refer this also.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. One thing I'm still not sure of is why the onTouchEvent first uses this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event); but then uses the super.onTouchEvent(event); to return the boolean.

Comment: @maca2kx `this` and `super` are 2 keywords in java having their own meaning,  when `this.` is used it means you want to access something within your class it can variable or method, and in your case  `this.gDetector.onTouchEvent(event)` it is accessing the method that's written in  `GestureDetectorCompat` which return false or true. and similarly `super.` when used  we can access all the variable and method of our immediate parent class, as you know now `onTouchEvent(event);` return `boolean` so `super.onTouchEvent(event);` it calling its parent to check for any other action, if so return true

Comment: I think I'm getting it. Thank you for your patience!